# Separation of a txt file?

Tags: python

I am Learning python. I have to read a file that contain:

00000 UNITED STATES 01000 ALABAMA01001 Autauga County, AL01003 Baldwin County, AL01005 Barbour County,AL01007 Bibb County, AL01009 Blount County, AL01011 Bullock County, 
and so on

My program is:

```
fips_fname ="path/FIPS_CountyName.txt"

f = open(fips_fname)

for row in f:

    print(row)
```

The output is:
00000 UNITED STATES

01000 ALABAMA

01001 Autauga County, AL

01003 Baldwin County, AL

01005 Barbour County, AL

01007 Bibb County, AL

01009 Blount County, AL

01011 Bullock County, AL

01013 Butler County, AL

Why? How does python decide what to put in a row and when to finish a new line and create a new one?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by separation? Are you asking why python is printing on a different row every time?

Comment: Are the different lines on different lines of the text file?

Comment: @KylePendergast I have edited it.

Comment: Strange, the rows should be separated line-by-line, not comma-separated-value by comma-separated-value. Are you sure the file contains "00000 UNITED STATES 01000 ALABAMA01001 Autauga County, AL01003 Baldwin County, AL01005 Barbour County,AL01007 Bibb County, AL01009 Blount County, AL01011 Bullock County" all on one line? Maybe there's some invisible whitespace that's mucking things up. If your text editor has an option like "show all special characters", try enabling that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lines are separated by `\r\n` in Windows, while the lines in the file you're reading are separated by `\n` only. You likely viewed the file with Notepad, which does not treat `\n` as a line separator, and saw the lines in the file displayed by Notepad as one long line. But when you iterate through the file object as a generator with Python, `\n` is recognized as a valid line separator, and therefore generates each line separately.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried to open the notepad file in word and he has the separation of what I read in python. How can I know if there is a separation in txt file or not?

Comment: You can know if there are line separators in a text file by using an editor more robust than Notepad, as you did with Word (the built-in WordPad would work as well). Almost all editors in Windows, except Notepad, as far as I know, recognizes `\n` as a line separator.